# What are these commands for (fglrx-updates installation)? And how to undo one of them?

Tags: fglrx, hybrid-graphics, mesa

My ubuntu 14.04 was not able to install fglrx-updates. I have two graphic cards (intel and amd). I searched on the net and found some answers related to it.
Firstly i tried this one:

```
sudo apt-get install libcheese*
```

(the first one did not work)

Secondly i tried this one from another answer:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa-drivers
```

(After the second one, i was able to install it successfully)

Now my question is, how can i undo the changes done by the first one, as i think it was not necessary.

Edit: This is what a post on the given link says about the first one:

"By running "sudo apt-get install libcheese*" you are basically reverting the mesa updates of 14.0.4.2. It'll remove all the new packages and give you the graphic stack compared to before installing the LTS enabled stack. Hence you can install fglrx again. You'll still have the new Utopic kernel though. I'm not sure if that's a good or bad thing. I can imagine some incompatibility issues without the new mesa stack, but if it works for you for the time being..."

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1424491

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if the package is required by any tool by running the command

```
apt-cache rdepends $package
```

in this case

```
apt-cache rdepends libcheese*
```

If it is not used by any other package, then it is safe to remove it.

To remove a software completely use

```
sudo apt-get purge $package
```

That is in this case

```
sudo apt-get purge libcheese*
```

To remove a software but with keeping its configuration files, use

```
sudo apt-get remove $package
```

that is

```
sudo apt-get remove libcheese*
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a package by:

```
sudo apt-get remove <packagename>
```

So in your case it will be:

```
sudo apt-get remove libcheese*
```

But I will suggest **not** to do this unless you have a strong reason to.

Running `sudo apt-get autoremove` will be a safe bet.

Comment: Actually i thought the same. But then i was not sure what it does. Can you tell me?

Comment: here is what the post in the link says: "By running "sudo apt-get install libcheese*" you are basically reverting the mesa updates of 14.0.4.2. It'll remove all the new packages and give you the graphic stack compared to before installing the LTS enabled stack. Hence you can install fglrx again.
You'll still have the new Utopic kernel though. I'm not sure if that's a good or bad thing. I can imagine some incompatibility issues without the new mesa stack, but if it works for you for the time being..."
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1424491